# Resetting JavaScript Functionality Without Reloading the Page

Tags: javascript

Not sure how to make this resetGame() function to work without using location.reload but then it messes with other stuff I'm trying to do. With the code shown below it kinda works until you get it wrong and click go again, now it gives you the class "fel" even if the typ is right. Here is entire code

```js
const eu = "europeiskt";
const jpn = "japanskt";
const fantasy = "fantasi";

function Svärd(typ, bild) {
  this.typ = typ;
  this.bild = bild;
}

let allaSvärd = [
  new Svärd(eu, "img/european/1.jpg"),
  new Svärd(eu, "img/european/2.jpg"),
  new Svärd(jpn, "img/japanese/1.jpg"),
  new Svärd(jpn, "img/japanese/2.jpg"),
  new Svärd(fantasy, "img/fantasy/1.jpg"),
  new Svärd(fantasy, "img/fantasy/2.jpg"),
];

const wrongAnswerDiv = document.getElementById("felsvar");
const wrongAnswerOkButton = wrongAnswerDiv.querySelector("button.osynlig");
const swordImages = document.querySelectorAll(".svärdbild");
const buttonRows = document.querySelectorAll(".knapprad");
const swordWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".svärdwrapper");
const congratMessage = document.getElementById("grattis");
const statisticsDiv = document.getElementById("statistik");

let correctGuesses = 0;

const EuBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-gissning="europeiskt"]');
const JpnBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-gissning="japanskt"]');
const fantasyBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-gissning="fantasi"]');

for (let i = 0; i < swordWrappers.length; i++) {
  swordWrappers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () =>
    buttonRows[i].classList.replace("osynlig", "synlig")
  );
  swordWrappers[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
    buttonRows[i].classList.replace("synlig", "osynlig")
  );
}

function resetGame() {
  swordImages.forEach((image) => {
    image.classList.remove("rätt");
    image.classList.remove("fel");
  });

  correctGuesses = 0;

  buttonRows.forEach((row) => {
    row.style.display = "block";
  });

  congratMessage.classList.add("osynlig");
  statisticsDiv.classList.add("osynlig");

  randomSword();
}

wrongAnswerOkButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame);

wrongAnswerOkButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  wrongAnswerDiv.classList.add("osynlig");
});

async function randomSword() {
  const idsResponse = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5500/sword/");
  const ids = await idsResponse.json();

  let allsvärd = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < swordImages.length; i++) {
    const randomId = ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)];
    const swordResponse = await fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:5500/sword/${randomId}`
    );
    const svard = await swordResponse.json();

    const newSvärd = new Svärd(svard.typ, svard.bild);
    allsvärd.push(newSvärd);

    swordImages[i].src = newSvärd.bild;

    const buttons = buttonRows[i].querySelectorAll("button");
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        const gissning = event.target.dataset.gissning;
        if (newSvärd.typ === gissning) {
          swordImages[i].classList.add("rätt");
          correctGuesses++;
        } else {
          swordImages[i].classList.add("fel");
        }
        buttonRows[i].style.display = "none";

        if (correctGuesses === 3) {
          congratMessage.classList.remove("osynlig");
        } else if (
          i === swordImages.length - 1 &&
          correctGuesses !== allaSvärd.length
        ) {
          wrongAnswerDiv.classList.remove("osynlig");
          wrongAnswerOkButton.classList.remove("osynlig");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

randomSword();
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gochi+Hand&display=swap";

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Gochi Hand";
}

div {
  padding: 4mm;
}

.lista>img {
  padding: 10px;

}

.svärdbild {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

img {
  border: 2mm ridge orange;
}

.rätt {
  border: 2mm ridge greenyellow;
}

.fel {
  border: 2mm ridge red;
}

div.resultat div section img {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1mm ridge brown;
}

img.small {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: none;
}

.synlig {
  visibility: visible;

}

.osynlig {
  visibility: hidden;
}

footer {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#footer::before {
  content: "⚔️";
}

#footer::after {
  content: "⚔️";
}

.overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
  z-index: 2;
}

.overlay>div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  color: darkgoldenrod;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
  border-style: dashed;

}

.felsvar {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
  z-index: 2;
}

.felsvar>div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.808);
  border-style: solid;
}

.svärdwrapper {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 25px;
  outline: dashed 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.404);

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bildwrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.pos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.knapprad {
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.233);
  background-color: rgba(202, 177, 177, 0.842);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
    <script defer src="svärd.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="container-fluid p-2">
      <div class="justify-content-center">
        <h1 class="text-center">Svärdgissarleken</h1>
        <h2 class="text-center">Gissa vilken typ de tre svärden är</h2>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm center-block text-center">
              <div class="svärdwrapper">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block svärdbild" />
                <div class="knapprad osynlig">
                  <p>Typ av svärd</p>
                  <button data-gissning="europeiskt">Europeiskt</button>
                  <button data-gissning="japanskt">Japanskt</button>
                  <button data-gissning="fantasi">Fantasy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm center-block text-center">
              <div class="svärdwrapper">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block svärdbild" />
                <div class="knapprad osynlig">
                  <p>Typ av svärd</p>
                  <button data-gissning="europeiskt">Europeiskt</button>
                  <button data-gissning="japanskt">Japanskt</button>
                  <button data-gissning="fantasi">Fantasy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm center-block text-center">
              <div class="svärdwrapper">
                <img class="img-responsive center-block svärdbild" />
                <div class="knapprad osynlig">
                  <p>Typ av svärd</p>
                  <button data-gissning="europeiskt">Europeiskt</button>
                  <button data-gissning="japanskt">Japanskt</button>
                  <button data-gissning="fantasi">Fantasy</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>

    <div id="grattis" class="osynlig overlay">
      <div>
        <h1 class="">⚔️⚔️Du gissade rätt!⚔️⚔️</h1>
        <div id="statistik"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="felsvar" class="felsvar osynlig">
      <div>
        <h2>Du lyckades inte gissa alla rätt, försök igen</h2>
        <button class="osynlig">Gör ett nytt försök</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 text-center">
        <hr />
        <!-- Lägg ditt namn här med hjälp av javascript!-->
        <span id="footer"></span>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried this

```
function resetGame() {
  swordImages.forEach((image) => {
    image.classList.remove("rätt");
    image.classList.remove("fel");
  });

  correctGuesses = 0;

  buttonRows.forEach((row) => {
    row.style.display = "block";
  });

  congratMessage.classList.add("osynlig");
  statisticsDiv.classList.add("osynlig");

  randomSword();
}
```

but it bugs the entire game and makes it not work like it does from the beggining

Comment: your question title can be a bit missguiding. Also it would help a lot if you could add the HTML revelant to your problem

Comment: What exactly does "bugs the entire game" mean?

Comment: @ChrisG I apologize for my mistakes I will try to make it better and do better posts in future, i've now added the HTML code

Comment: Sorry, @Pointy. I should have been more clear, but it's kind of hard for me to explain since I don't really know what's happening. The code changes completely after the resetGame function, so now instead of being able to correctly identify the right guess, every guess is given the CSS class 'fel' (meaning 'wrong') when it should be 'rätt' (meaning 'right') like in the beginning. Additionally, the 'felsvar' div gets added even if the guess is correct, and the 'congratmessage' displays even when not all three swords have been correctly guessed.

Comment: I think this is part of the problem, `const wrongAnswerOkButton = wrongAnswerDiv.querySelector("button");` you wronganswerokbutton there should be a single element right? but you are using `querySelector("button")` when there are multiple `button` elements in your HTML

Comment: Good eye! @ChrisG I changed it to const wrongAnswerOkButton = wrongAnswerDiv.querySelector("button.osynlig");
But the issue with the resetGame function seems to still stand, no errors in console so I'm not sure what to look for as it looks correct to me

Comment: can you add your css? what those classes that you add or remove do? just asking cuz I can't reproduce the problem on my end

Comment: @ChrisG yes sir thanks for the help btw, CSS is also added now

Comment: k so I edited your question to create a snippet of your code, to reproduce the problem. When the edit request is approved you will be able to run the code from here

Comment: @ChrisG Great thank you! I approved the request

Comment: Whenever I press the buttons the game does nothing tho or am I not understanding the code well?

Comment: @ChrisG no ofcourse i just realized im using a local "api" which the randomsword is pulling the images from its a json fil with multiple images and "typ". I guess this kinda makes it hard to resolve the issue ..

Comment: yeah, is hard to reproduce the problem so I can only check for errors in the code by eye at the moment

Comment: this part might also be part of the problem `const buttons = buttonRows[i].querySelectorAll("button");`

Comment: you are adding yet another event to all buttons in your HTML, including your `wrongAnswerOkButton` which resets the game and this is probably why is messing up the entire game. You should probably add that eventListener to all buttons with the exception of that one

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `const buttons = buttonRows[i].querySelectorAll("button");` what this code does is: It gets every element in your HTML with the `<button>` tag including your button which calls your `resetGame()` function. So that means that aside from resetting the game you are adding a new event to it `button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {` which is probably why is messing everything up after you press it.

What you need to do is get all the buttons with the `data-gissning` attribute only and exclude your `wrongAnswerOkButton` and you can do it like this

replace:

```
const buttons = buttonRows[i].querySelectorAll("button");
```

for this:

```
const buttons = buttonRows[i].querySelectorAll("button[data-gissning]");
```

and that should solve the problem

```js
const eu = "europeiskt";
const jpn = "japanskt";
const fantasy = "fantasi";

function Svärd(typ, bild) {
  this.typ = typ;
  this.bild = bild;
}

let allaSvärd = [
  new Svärd(eu, "img/european/1.jpg"),
  new Svärd(eu, "img/european/2.jpg"),
  new Svärd(jpn, "img/japanese/1.jpg"),
  new Svärd(jpn, "img/japanese/2.jpg"),
  new Svärd(fantasy, "img/fantasy/1.jpg"),
  new Svärd(fantasy, "img/fantasy/2.jpg"),
];

const wrongAnswerDiv = document.getElementById("felsvar");
const wrongAnswerOkButton = wrongAnswerDiv.querySelector("button.osynlig");
const swordImages = document.querySelectorAll(".svärdbild");
const buttonRows = document.querySelectorAll(".knapprad");
const swordWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".svärdwrapper");
const congratMessage = document.getElementById("grattis");
const statisticsDiv = document.getElementById("statistik");

let correctGuesses = 0;

const EuBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-gissning="europeiskt"]');
const JpnBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-gissning="japanskt"]');
const fantasyBtn = document.querySelector('button[data-gissning="fantasi"]');

for (let i = 0; i < swordWrappers.length; i++) {
  swordWrappers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () =>
    buttonRows[i].classList.replace("osynlig", "synlig")
  );
  swordWrappers[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () =>
    buttonRows[i].classList.replace("synlig", "osynlig")
  );
}

function resetGame() {
  swordImages.forEach((image) => {
    image.classList.remove("rätt");
    image.classList.remove("fel");
  });

  correctGuesses = 0;

  buttonRows.forEach((row) => {
    row.style.display = "block";
  });

  congratMessage.classList.add("osynlig");
  statisticsDiv.classList.add("osynlig");

  randomSword();
}

wrongAnswerOkButton.addEventListener("click", resetGame);

wrongAnswerOkButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("wrongAnswerOkButton pressed");
  wrongAnswerDiv.classList.add("osynlig");
});

async function randomSword() {
  const idsResponse = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5500/sword/");
  const ids = await idsResponse.json();

  let allsvärd = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < swordImages.length; i++) {
    const randomId = ids[Math.floor(Math.random() * ids.length)];
    const swordResponse = await fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:5500/sword/${randomId}`
    );
    const svard = await swordResponse.json();

    const newSvärd = new Svärd(svard.typ, svard.bild);
    allsvärd.push(newSvärd);

    swordImages[i].src = newSvärd.bild;

    const buttons = buttonRows[i].querySelectorAll("button[data-gissning]");
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
      button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        const gissning = event.target.dataset.gissning;
        if (newSvärd.typ === gissning) {
          swordImages[i].classList.add("rätt");
          correctGuesses++;
        } else {
          swordImages[i].classList.add("fel");
        }
        buttonRows[i].style.display = "none";

        if (correctGuesses === 3) {
          congratMessage.classList.remove("osynlig");
        } else if (
          i === swordImages.length - 1 &&
          correctGuesses !== allaSvärd.length
        ) {
          wrongAnswerDiv.classList.remove("osynlig");
          wrongAnswerOkButton.classList.remove("osynlig");
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

randomSword();
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gochi+Hand&display=swap";
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Gochi Hand";
}

div {
  padding: 4mm;
}

.lista>img {
  padding: 10px;
}

.svärdbild {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

img {
  border: 2mm ridge orange;
}

.rätt {
  border: 2mm ridge greenyellow;
}

.fel {
  border: 2mm ridge red;
}

div.resultat div section img {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1mm ridge brown;
}

img.small {
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
  border: none;
}

.synlig {
  visibility: visible;
}

.osynlig {
  visibility: hidden;
}

footer {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#footer::before {
  content: "⚔️";
}

#footer::after {
  content: "⚔️";
}

.overlay {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
  z-index: 2;
}

.overlay>div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  color: darkgoldenrod;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.808);
  border-style: dashed;
}

.felsvar {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.418);
  z-index: 2;
}

.felsvar>div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.808);
  border-style: solid;
}

.svärdwrapper {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 25px;
  outline: dashed 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.404);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bildwrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.pos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.knapprad {
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(165, 42, 42, 0.233);
  background-color: rgba(202, 177, 177, 0.842);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png" />
  <script defer src="svärd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main class="container-fluid p-2">
    <div class="justify-content-center">
      <h1 class="text-center">Svärdgissarleken</h1>
      <h2 class="text-center">Gissa vilken typ de tre svärden är</h2>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm center-block text-center">
            <div class="svärdwrapper">
              <img class="img-responsive center-block svärdbild" />
              <div class="knapprad osynlig">
                <p>Typ av svärd</p>
                <button data-gissning="europeiskt">Europeiskt</button>
                <button data-gissning="japanskt">Japanskt</button>
                <button data-gissning="fantasi">Fantasy</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm center-block text-center">
            <div class="svärdwrapper">
              <img class="img-responsive center-block svärdbild" />
              <div class="knapprad osynlig">
                <p>Typ av svärd</p>
                <button data-gissning="europeiskt">Europeiskt</button>
                <button data-gissning="japanskt">Japanskt</button>
                <button data-gissning="fantasi">Fantasy</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm center-block text-center">
            <div class="svärdwrapper">
              <img class="img-responsive center-block svärdbild" />
              <div class="knapprad osynlig">
                <p>Typ av svärd</p>
                <button data-gissning="europeiskt">Europeiskt</button>
                <button data-gissning="japanskt">Japanskt</button>
                <button data-gissning="fantasi">Fantasy</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>

  <div id="grattis" class="osynlig overlay">
    <div>
      <h1 class="">⚔️⚔️Du gissade rätt!⚔️⚔️</h1>
      <div id="statistik"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="felsvar" class="felsvar osynlig">
    <div>
      <h2>Du lyckades inte gissa alla rätt, försök igen</h2>
      <button class="osynlig">Gör ett nytt försök</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6 text-center">
      <hr />
      <!-- Lägg ditt namn här med hjälp av javascript!-->
      <span id="footer"></span>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would also recommend putting ALL code in functions instead of having some code randomly floating around. It will help in understanding what's going on.